# How does the Mandalorian succeed in having his face scanned?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-mandalorian

In Season 2, Ep 7, the Mandalorian has to take his imperial trooper helmet off in order to have his face scanned by an imperial data terminal.

He is successful in doing it.

How did this happen? His face should not be recognised by any imperial data server.

Comment: I wondered this too ... the only thing I could think was that the terminal 'scans' i.e. captures your facial features and records it as part of the session.  It's not part of the authentication of the user.  Tenuous I know.

Comment: @iandotkelly, that would be very poor security protocol; I think the writers of this episode would regret this decision.

Comment: Honestly I don't think there is a satisfactory answer to this.  It's a rare example of very poor writing in The Mandalorian.  Its clearly a manufactured excuse to get Pedro Pascal's face in the show again, and show the audience how far Mando will go to get The Child Back.

Comment: Pedro Pascal has apparently been complaining about the fact that his face is never seen. They may have done this for his benefit.

Comment: Technically , it shouldn't since he doesn't show his face at all, but it should signal that that he isn't an imperial trooper at least.

Comment: Mysterious story that will be resolved in future episodes;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My take on this is that this might be part of the scanning process Mayfeld mentioned when they were overlooking the transport route.

> "When you get scanned and your genetic signatur shows up on any
> new-republic register, you're gonna be detected and it's guns out."

Since Mando is not part of these registers (I assume) he could scan his face without tripping the alarm.

I guess as "remnants" of the empire they might not have the possibilities to create a record on each and every one of their troopers/captains/squads/etc., so tapping into republic records to keep unauthorized personel from accessing the terminals is the next best thing. People like Mando being off the records might either be an oversight or a calculated risk.

Answer (score 2):

They scan the face to monitor who used the terminal.

The Empire is in ruins and there are many different factions, so they probably don't have records for every troop from offworld anymore.

They might not even keep such a database for the same reasons that the Rebellion wouldn't have - OpSec.

But... they'd probably be able to slice into official republic databases and keep tabs on their operatives.

They might not auth against a central Imperial database anymore, but they can certainly auth against their hacked Republic info and sound an alarm if they get a hit.

Comment: Is your response based on any material or is it only assumptions ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this just seemed like a plot device to get his helmet off during the scene, however I think it could be best explained by saying the Empire was, oddly, not concerned about scanning to match authorized profiles in the system and more concerned about recording who accessed the information.  (Long story short, it doesn't make sense and someone should be fired in Imperial Infosec.)  The terminal gave up what would presumably be classified information on Moff Gideon's deployment.  This is why it made sense to let Mayfield get the information since he was ex-Empire (mind you, it would make as much sense for him to still have an active security profile). But he was too concerned about being spotted by his old CO in the mess hall. Therefore at the last minute they switched. I'll agree the possible in-universe explanation is flimsy.  Frankly, neither Mayfield nor Mando should have been able to access that information.

When lacking logical explanations in the GFFA, the Force wills it to be.